# Facebook php sdk : oauth is triggering redirect uri again and again

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Latest Php sdk for facebook `login` authentication for my application.

The problem which I am facing is after facebook authentication its not going to redirect uri at once . It keeps trying again and again , finally after few attempts it redirects to the uri which I have set.

Also sometimes it does not reach at all. I have tried all the solutions provided in the various post still could not get any help . Please provide me the actual solution.

Comment: There is another option, You can use facebook javascript sdk, it will reduce your server hit and also increase user experience more faster.:)

Comment: `Please provide me the actual solution`-without even looking at any of your code :O I don't think that's possible..